# Java Regex to match a whole word with any combinationof special character

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a regex that will match with my string for any combination of special characters. My string may contain a special character or may not contain any special character and the position of special characters is also not fixed they may be anywhere in the string.

I have tried below code

```
String myString = new String("{{Hello}}");
    System.out.println(myString);
    System.out.print("Return Value :");
    System.out.println(myString.matches("\\*"+myString+"\\*"));
```

But I am always getting the below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 1
```

Possible Combinations of `myString are "{Abc}","{{#DER#&@}}", "%^&my%%**WORLD", ":,WhatAre$#$YouDOING:$$"`

Most of the time special characters will surround the string(hello). But there count is not defined. They can be unequal on either of the side and there may be also the case that they are not even present(surround) with the string.

Comment: The curly brace is a regex metacharacter, so you must escape it in the pattern

Comment: That is only one case that i have mentioned . There can be any special character anywhere.

Comment: This question is very unclear to me. Can you please post examples of valid and invalid data

Comment: Your question is not clear, but if you're going to use some arbitrary string as part of a regex pattern, you need to escape all regex metacharacters first.  I don't use Java at this time, but there's probably a function for that.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza : Added data

Comment: @LukStorms I think you mean [Pattern.quote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String))

Comment: No the problem with the `String.contains` method is that if my input string is "event" and if i encounter "prevent" in my file/line it will return true

Comment: @AnuragSharma So you have a fixed string like "Hello" and want to match strings which have that fixed string interspersed with spl characters? Like "H%ello" or "Hell^o$#"? Or can spl characters only surround your fixed string?

Comment: Most of the time they will surround the string(hello) is this key. But there count is not defined. They can be unequal on either of the side and there may be also the case that they are not even present(surround) with the string.

Comment: @AnuragSharma: Try `myString.matches(".*\\b"+ Pattern.quote(myString)  + "\\b.*")`

Comment: @anu I think that’s close, but `myString` can start/end with non-word chars too. An alternation plus look arounds would do it.

Comment: Good point, in that case `myString.matches(".*(?<!\\w)" + Pattern.quote(myString) + "(?!\\w).*")` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the target, but to prevent matches when the target is *part* of a larger word (eg `event` in the text `prevent`), add a word boundary if the end of the target is a word character:

```
str.matches(".*(?=\\b\\w|\\W)"
  + Pattern.quote(myString)
  + "(?<=\\w\\b|\\W).*")
```

Comment: Works for all cases. Thanks a lot

Comment: This logic is failing when `myString={LOGGER}` and my line contains `{{LOGGER}}`. It is still giving me match there. It should match only when the whole word is matched.

Comment: @AnuragSharma Please explain (in detail) why `{{LOGGER}}` should not be a match when the target is `{LOGGER}`.

Comment: Because it is not matching the whole word. Example: suppose you are searching for 'event' in your file using Ctrl+f and you enable 'whole word' and now suppose your file contains 'prevent'(it also has 'event'(your search key)) then it doesn't give you a match on 'prevent' as you have enabled 'whole word' search

Comment: @anu I understand when the search term is an actual word of letters, but what is a “word” when the search term has non-word chars at the end? You haven’t answered my question at all. Please talk about `{LOGGER}` *only* and what the exact problem is with it matching `{{LOGGER}}`.

Comment: The problem is that after finding a match with key i would be replacing them with there values that are stored in a property file. Suppose my key is {LOGGER} and its value is "mypassword" and if my file contains {{LOGGER}} then as per your code it will match and when i will do a replacement then it would be like {mypassword} instead of 'mypassword'

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I understood of your requirement, this should work:

```
String fixedString = "hello";
String stringToMatch = "{{hello}}";
String pattern = "\\W*"+Pattern.quote(fixedString)+"\\W*";
System.out.println("Match ?" + stringToMatch.matches(pattern));
```

It surrounds the fixed string with a non-word character repeat (0 or more times).

Comment: Thanks. It is working whenever the string is surrounded by any combination and number of special characters.

Comment: what's if my fixed string is this:
`String fixedString = "{{hello}}";`

Comment: Updated @AnuragSharma

Comment: It is giving me true in below case:
`String fixedString = "{hello}";
String stringToMatch = "{{hello}}";`
it should return `false`

Comment: Why? It satisfies your condition of zero or more spl characters surrounding the given string..

Comment: Yes. But the requirement is to match the whole word. Below regex is the solution for it:
`".*(?=\\b)"+ Pattern.quote(key)+ "(?<=\\b).*"`

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to achieve. Your input and regex is same string. However to resolve error in current program you can do below.

You can define regex like this -

```
   private static final String REGEX = "\\{\\{Hello\\}\\}";
```

And pass it to matches() method. That should do your job. You will have to escape these special characters before you pass the regex to matches() method.

Comment: Its just any example . Possible string values can be in any form. Some of the possible cases are : 
`{Abc}","{{#DER#&@}}", "%^&my%%**WORLD", ":,WhatAre$#$YouDOING:$$"`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for pattern matches method is wrong, the argument for matches is regex.
Use the correct syntax is below.

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z._ ^%$#!~@,-{}]+";
String input = "{{word ofregex}}";
System.out.println(input.matches(regex));
System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regex, input));
```

Comment: It returns false for below input :
`String input = "**hey**";` or `String input = "{{**hey**}}";`

Comment: You need to add the special characters in the regex, which you want to allow, for example add "\*" 
    String regex = "[a-zA-Z._ ^%$#!~@,-{}\*]+";  
and then check

Answer (score 0):

Clearly define which characters you are looking for. From the examples you provided in the comments, some test cases are:

1. `{Abc}`
2. `{{#DER#&@}}`
3. `%^&my%%**WORLD`
4. `:,WhatAre$#$YouDOING:$$`

Many of these characters need to be escaped and you also need to remember that a `\` in a `String` needs to be written as `\\` (escaped).

Taking your second example (the one with DER in it), a regex such as `[#\^&@]` would match. So one possible solution is to identify all of the special characters you want to look for and place them in a character class (defined by the stuff between the square brackets) escaping as appropriate.

A helpful resource for regex testing is [here](https://www.regex101.com) and another for more in-depth study of regular expressions is [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info).